# PHPExcel - Finding First Column With blank cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

Trying to locate the first blank cell in a column. The idea is to pick a column that I know has to have a value (in this case, JOB_NUMBER) and scan through it until a blank cell is found. The code below, in my mind, should do that. However, it never stops. I imagine it is stuck in the `while` loop, but I don't understand why.

Code:

```
<?php 
require('./Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
ini_set('memory_limit', 2000000000);  

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

    public function __construct($fromColumn, $toColumn) {
        $this->columns = array();
        $toColumn++;
        while ($fromColumn !== $toColumn) {
        $this->columns[] = $fromColumn++;
        }
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          // Read columns from 'A' to 'AF'
          if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}

$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter('A', 'AF'); 

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("NORTH") );
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$r = 3500;
while(isset($maxrow_north) != 1){
    $cellvalue = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetByName('NORTH')->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $r);

    if(isset($cellvalue) != 1){
        $maxrow_north = $r; 
    } elseif($r > 4000) {
        echo "It's over 4000!";
    } else {
        $r = $r++;
        } 
}


echo $maxrow_north;
?>
```

**Some more background**

I am having admins upload `.xlsx` `.xls` or `.csv` files into an html form. The code, above, is the handler. I have limited the number of columns seen because the original creator of the `.xlsx` file thought it would be a great idea to have the columns go all the way out to XCF.

The rows also go all the way out to somewhere around 10,000. So, I want to find the first blank row and stop there.

**TIA!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use

```
if(isset($cellvalue) != 1){
```

A cell value always exists even if it's an empty string or a null: and you're not testing the actual cell value, but the existence of a cell.... simply **get()** ting a cell will create a new empty cell object if one didn't already exist

You need to test the actual value stored in the cell

```
if($cellvalue->getValue() === NULL || $cellvalue->getValue() === '') {
    $maxrow_north = $r;
```

And if you're trying to find the **first** blank cell in the column, then `break` once you've found it rather than carry on iterating till you reach your max

(Note, doesn't check for rich text in cells)

**EDIT**

Example, that also allows for merged cells

```
function testInMergeRangeNotParent($objWorksheet, $cell)
{
    $inMergeRange = false;
    foreach($objWorksheet->getMergeCells() as $mergeRange) {
        if ($cell->isInRange($mergeRange)) {
            $range = PHPExcel_Cell::splitRange($mergeRange);
            list($startCell) = $range[0];
            if ($cell->getCoordinate() !== $startCell) {
                $inMergeRange = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $inMergeRange;
}


$column = 2;  // Column to check
$max = 4000;
echo 'Get First blank row in column ', $column, PHP_EOL;
$r = 3500;  // Starting row
while(true){
    $cell = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetByName('NORTH')->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $r);
    if ($cell->getValue() === NULL && 
        !testInMergeRangeNotParent($objPHPExcelReader->getSheetByName('NORTH'), $cell)) {
        break;
    }elseif($r > $max) {
        echo "It's over $max !";
        break;
    }
    $r++;
}
echo 'First blank row in column ', $column, ' is ', $r, PHP_EOL;
```